# Inserting Multiple of same records into SQL temp table based on value in column

Tags: sql, loops

So I have table with the following records:

[image: Source table]

I want to create a script to iteratively look at the Cnt_Repeat column and insert that same record in a temp table X times depending on the value in Cnt_Repeat so it would look like the following table:

[image: Table of results]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method supported by most databases is the use of recursive CTEs.  The exact syntax might vary, but the idea is:

```
with cte as (
      select loannum, document, cnt_repeat, 1 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select loannum, document, cnt_repeat, lev + 1
      from cte
      where lev < cnt_repeat
     )
select loannum, document, cnt_repeat
from cte;
```